# Radio button flag

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton

Boa tarde, possuo uma aplicação mobile escrita em MobileUI e JS, onde tenho um alert para a função de troca de empresa. Nesse alert possui os inputs radio, que é para selecionar apenas uma das opções. Gostaria que ao abrir o alert ele sempre viesse com o input selecionado marcado, porém ele sempre me trás em branco.

Poderiam me ajudar? Segue abaixo código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo JavaScript

```
var empresaSelect

function trocarEmpresa(){
    map.setClickable(false)
    alert({
        id: 'alertEmpresa',
        title: 'Trocar Empresa',
        message: 'Realize a troca de empresa!',
        template: 'empresaVendedor',
        width: '60%',
        buttons:[
            {
                label: 'OK',
                onclick: function() {
                    closeAlert('alertEmpresa')
                    map.setClickable(true)
                    findFormVendedor()
                    myLocation()
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Cancelar',
                onclick: function() {
                    closeAlert('alertEmpresa')
                    map.setClickable(true)
                }
            }
        ]
    })
}

function selectedEmpresa(index) {

    empresaSelect = empresas.filter(function (e, i) {
        return i == index ? e : null
    })

    empresaSelect = empresaSelect[0]
}

document.addEventListener('backPage', function() {
    closeAlert('alertEmpresa')
})
```

Arquivo HTML

```
<div class="hidden" id="empresaVendedor">
        <div class="list">
            <div class="item" data="empresas">
                <h2>${razaoSocial}</h2>
                <div class="right">
                    <input name="radio-emp" type="radio" class="teal" onclick="selectedEmpresa($$index)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar o estado do input como `checked` direto na tag html? Tipo assim:  `<input checked name="radio-emp" type="radio" class="teal" onclick="selectedEmpresa($$index)">` ?

Answer (score 0):

Bem é algo fácil de se resolver, utilize a propriedade "Checked" do input (HTML)
No seu código:

```html
    <div class="hidden" id="empresaVendedor">
        <div class="list">
            <div class="item" data="empresas">
                <h2>${razaoSocial}</h2>
                <div class="right">
                    <input name="radio-emp" type="radio" class="teal" onclick="selectedEmpresa($$index)" checked >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Referencia: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp